# Help with function in template.php

Tags: nodes, theming

Drupal 7.

Can anyone spot what could be wrong with this function?  I'm just trying to pull a taxonomy term or its parent.  The taxonomy is called "pubissue."

In template.php:

```
 function ain_core_getpubname() {

// Load the node from unaliased url
if ((arg(0) == 'node') && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
$node = node_load(arg(1));}


// first find out if it's level two or not
$query = "SELECT t1.tid, t1.parent FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy t1 JOIN field_revision_field_pubissue t2 ON t1.tid = t2.field_pubissue_tid WHERE t2.entity_id = ".$node->nid;

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));

        $mytid = $row["tid"];
        $myparent = $row["parent"];

    if ($myparent == 0) {

        // No parent, top level
        $query = "SELECT t1.name FROM taxonomy_term_data t1 WHERE tid = ".$mytid;

        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $pubname = $row["name"];        
    }

    else {

        $query = "SELECT t1.name FROM taxonomy_term_data t1 WHERE tid = ".$myparent;

        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $pubname = $row["name"];

        }

print $pubname;
```

}

Then in my node.tpl.php file:

```
 <!-- Begin Publication -->
    <div class="<?php print $node->type; ?>-pubname"><?php ain_core_getpubname() ?></div>
<!-- End Publication -->
```

OK, so going with the suggestion below:

```
function ain_core_getpubname() {

// Load the node from unaliased url
if ((arg(0) == 'node') && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
$node = node_load(arg(1));}


// first find out if it's level two or not
$query = "SELECT t1.tid, t1.parent FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy t1 JOIN field_revision_field_pubissue t2 ON t1.tid = t2.field_pubissue_tid WHERE t2.entity_id = ".$node->nid;

    $result = db_query($query);
    $row = db_fetch_array($result);

        $mytid = $row->tid;
        $myparent = $row->parent;

    if ($myparent == 0) {

        // No parent, top level
        $pubname = db_query("SELECT t1.name FROM taxonomy_term_data t1 WHERE tid = ".$mytid)->fetchField();
    }

    else {

        $pubname = db_query("SELECT t1.name FROM taxonomy_term_data t1 WHERE tid = ".$myparent)->fetchField();

        }

print $pubname;
```

Still not working.  Will continue to troubleshoot, I think I am on the right track.  Thanks again.

Comment: First take a look at the [Database abstraction layer](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/group/database/7) and check out how to access (e.g. [db_query](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_query/7)) your database the drupal way. Second there is a missing `;` in your node.tpl.php next to `ain_core_getpubname()`.

Comment: It looks like you've been reading the Drupal 6 documentation. There is no db_fetch_array() in D7. In D7, you can do `$result = db_query($query)->fetchAssoc();` or `$result = db_query($query)->fetchObject();`. You can also iterate over $result with a foreach loop (see http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#dbtng).

Answer (score 1):

Your queries should look something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT t1.tid, t1.parent FROM {taxonomy_term_hierarchy} t1 JOIN {field_revision_field_pubissue} t2 ON t1.tid = t2.field_pubissue_tid WHERE t2.entity_id = :nid";
$result = db_query($query,array(':nid' => $node->nid));
// Result is returned as a iterable object that returns a stdClass object on each iteration (@see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_query/7#comment-7019)
```

After all I would suggest you check out the [drupal taxonomy api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/7). Using something like [taxonomy_get_tree()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7) could be much better.

EDIT:

Using the taxonomy api I would say what you want to do would be something like:

```
$parents = taxonomy_get_parents($tid);
if(!empty($parents)) {
    // use whatever you need from your $parents
}
else {
    $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
    // use whatever you need from the term (No parent, top level)
}
```

EDIT 2: fixed code example...

Comment: Thanks - I agree, I probably should be using taxonomy_get_tree().  So would it just be:

`taxonomy_get_tree(10, $mytid)`

or 

`taxonomy_get_tree(10, $myparent)`

(assuming 10 is the vid of the pubissue vocab)

Comment: OK, so how do I get the $tid value?